# Selenium / Python, how to find and invoke a Javascript function with specific HTML text as hyperlink?

Tags: python, selenium

Using **Selenium/Python**, how do I find this element and click?

**`<a href="javascript:getZipFile(0,750,'');" class="">All</a>`**

the parameters in **`getZipFile()`** are random, may be different, and there are multiple **`getZipFile()`** references

in the HTML, but only one with the text **`All`**

Answer (score 1):

Try to find by `link text`:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("All").click()
```

Or `xpath`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'getZipFile') and text()='All']").click()
```

Comment: OK, that works.  Now it starts downloading the ZIP file, but immediately says "Failed" in the lower left hand corner message area that tracks/displays the progress of a download.  There is no explanation why.  The directory where it is set to go exists and has read/write permissions for everyone.